# What's the difference between "equery depends" and "equery depgraph"?

Tags: gentoo

```
xi@localhost /usr/src $ equery depgraph gcc | wc -l
872
xi@localhost /usr/src $ equery depends gcc
 * These packages depend on gcc:
app-admin/eselect-python-20100321 (>=sys-devel/gcc-3.4)
sys-devel/llvm-3.0-r2 (>=sys-devel/gcc-3.0)
sys-libs/glibc-2.15-r3 (>=sys-devel/gcc-3.4.4)
                       (arm ? >=sys-devel/gcc-4.1.0)
                       (x86 ? >=sys-devel/gcc-4.3)
                       (amd64 ? >=sys-devel/gcc-4.3)
                       (ppc ? >=sys-devel/gcc-4.1.0)
                       (ppc64 ? >=sys-devel/gcc-4.1.0)
xi@localhost /usr/src $ equery depgraph
Display a direct dependency graph for a given package

xi@localhost /usr/src $ equery depends
List all packages that depend on a atom given query
```

Comment: "depends" - those 2 packages depend on gcc? How few!

Comment: What are direct dependencies? What are indirect dependencies? Direct of gcc - those which depend on gcc (to be dependent - is to require gcc). Indirect of gcc = gcc are dependent of those packages? That is all the difference?

Comment: how to undertand directly and what's the difference . Depgraph indirect - there is a separate option. So it is not strict the difference. May be it's better to say in what purpose do they serve?

Comment: How they are usually used, in what context of thought and mind. This is my first experience with linux I use emerge to install and emerge --unmerge to uninstall. +may be some USE flags USE="" emerge, that's all. I've read a lot. But I don't know the way of thought in general.

Answer (score 3):

`equery depgraph <atom>` will list you a graph of the dependencies  needs to be installed

`equery depend <atom>` lists all packages that directly need  to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

`equery depgraph <atom>` outputs all the required dependencies for *atom*.

**Use case: pre-install considerations**

- Where is software based on
- Is it worth the extra amount of packages?
- Prevent a whole tree of additional dependencies by USE flag tuning

**Example**: qt and kde libraries can  be pulled in while you are gnome user. You may be able to prevent it by disabling `qt` and `kde` USE flags. Or choose to find an alternative package offerings a similar solution.

`equery depends <atom>` gives reversed dependency resolution. So what other packages are pulled in by *atom*.

**Use case: [blocked packages](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Working/Portage#Blocked_packages)**

An installed package can prevent an update.

- What other packages pulled this atom in?
- Is it an absolute requirement or can we get rid of it by disabling an USE flag?
- Consider if we need the package asking for this atom or if we really want to update.

Some more use cases for both commands:

- portage tree dependency bug hunting
- System cleanup